# Como manter cabeçalho fixo sem alteração de altura ao usar scroll

Tags: css, html5

Em minha página tenho uma cabeçalho fixo no topo, mas quando rolo a página e retorno ao topo a altura do cabeçalho é alterada, fiz algumas tentativas, como retirar a essa linha, eu apaguei a div.hidden-header, pois como ela te um height fixo, ela está empurrando o header.clearfix para baixo

```
<div class="hidden-header"></div>
```

A página pode ser vista aqui: [Projeto](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/garantia.php)

Comment: Tem algum código javascript alterando o `padding-top` e `padding-bottom` das tags `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caro, dentro do seu arquivo *script.js* existe uma função `scrollPage()`, está responsável pela alteração de seu cabeçalho, segue abaixo a função.

```
function scrollPage() {
    var sy = scrollY();
    if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
        $('.top-bar').slideUp(300);
        $("header").addClass("fixed-header");
        $('.navbar-brand').css({ 'padding-top' : 19 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 19 + "px" });

        if (/iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 479 ){
            $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" })
        }else{
            $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 20 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 20 + "px" })
            $('.search-side').css({ 'margin-top' : -7 + "px" });
        };

    }
    else {
        $('.top-bar').slideDown(300);
        $("header").removeClass("fixed-header");
        $('.navbar-brand').css({ 'padding-top' : 27 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 27 + "px" });

        if (/iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 479 ){
            $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" })
        }else{
            $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 28 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 28 + "px" })
            $('.search-side').css({ 'margin-top' : 0  + "px" });
        };

    }
    didScroll = false;
}
```

Sendo assim você pode comentar a função, caso não haja algum empecilho ou simplesmente alterar estas linhas:

```
$('.search-side').css({ 'margin-top' : -7 + "px" });
```

para

```
$('.search-side').css({ 'margin-top' : 0 + "px" });
```

e

```
$('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 28 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 28 + "px" })
```

para

```
$('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" })
```

A alternativa de alterar os valores, testei substituindo o código pelo console do Chrome em seu site e deu certo.

Comment: Olá @devgaspa, agradeço a grande ajuda, solucionou um sinistro para mim.